# Accurately count active users? (PHP + MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, session

Basically, I've been trying to get an accurate measure of how many active users my site has. I'm tracking sessions on the DB, and also doing some clean-up based on the USER_AGENT to remove bots/spiders/crawlers (very basic stuff though). 
What I get is a very high number of sessions, even after removing duplicate sessions for the same IP. In fact the number of sessions is 10x larger than what Google Analytics and other User Tracking systems report, so there's gotta be something I'm doing wrong.

Here's part of the code where I keep track of sessions:

```
//Start session if not active already
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

//Determine whether bot or browser
$bots = array(
    'bot',
    'crawler',
    'yahoo',
    'spider',
    'google',
    '$^'
);
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$uam = preg_match('/'.implode('|', $bots).'/i', $ua);
$uatype = ($uam)?'bot':'browser';

//Add session to DB if new or expired
if ($_SESSION['renew'] < time() || !isset($_SESSION['renew'])) {
    $_SESSION['renew'] = time() + 900; //15 minutes
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . SESSIONS . " (session_id, user_id,
           renew, user_ip, type, useragent) VALUES ('" . session_id() . "',
           '" . $myuser->get('user_id') . "', " . $_SESSION['renew'] . ",
           '" . $myuser->get('ip') . "', '$uatype', '$ua') 
           ON DUPLICATE KEY
           UPDATE renew = " . $_SESSION['renew'] . ",
           user_id = '" . $myuser->get('user_id') . "'";
    $site_db->query($sql);

    $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . SESSIONS . '
           WHERE renew < ' . time();
    $site_db->query($sql);
}
```

So, I'm storing the session info in DB and then renewing / expiring every 15 minutes as necessary.

If I then query the DB for sessions that are from browsers, with unique IP addresses, I get about 10x as many as JS systems are reporting.
Even if I try to reduce the number by only counting entries that have their first two octets of the IP address unique, I'm still way over.

Any tips on what I could be doing wrong on my session tracking?

The query to get the counts goes like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(DISTINCT(user_ip) FROM ".SESSIONS." WHERE type = 'browser'";
```

As a note, the bot trap is already discarding about 66% of the sessions. If I didn't do that, I would get close to 40x as many "active users" as GA reports.

Thanks.

Comment: which field is unique/primary?

Comment: the session_id is the primary key of the SESSIONS table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe storing those records and then do a query like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . SESSIONS . ' WHERE renew BETWEEN ' . $expire-900. ' AND ' .$expire;
```

And for performance reasons, let a cronjob do your deleting.
For example: Delete every record that expired an hour ago. And do that every half hour or something.

Comment: [SO answers should contain answers, not just links (which might expire)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/161492).

Comment: But I'm already clearing the sessions very often, so that query wouldn't help. All results are within the expire range you specify.

As for doing the delete in a cron job, that is a good idea, to reduce unnecessary delete statements once a new user visits.

Comment: I dont get your comment. Which problem is left now?

Comment: Also, time() returns miliseconds and you're adding 900 milisec instead of 900 sec. Try it again

Comment: Also, session_start doesn't need that if condition. And when  is this true (renew == '')

Comment: @HansElsen The problem is that I'm getting tons of sessions that apparently are not actual user sessions (javascript utilities report far less than I get using the code above).  

Also, time() return seconds [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php), so time()+900 is the correct way to add 15 minutes.  

The (renew == '') never happens anymore, it was from a previous version, I've removed that from the actual code.

Comment: If you must must log only actual users, then you should check for $uatype too.